# Disable notification sound in android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I want to create a notification without any sounds. How can I do this?Thanks.

This is my code: [Link](http://s6.picofile.com/d/8285957550/da2fdb09-7757-4766-acaf-5aa0e4a32630/NewMessageNotification.txt)

Excuse me my friends.I could not put my code here.

Thank you so much.

Comment: cant you use some safe site to upload it like dropbox or drive?

Comment: Sorry, no I can't.

Comment: please try to upload your codes in a safer place....!

Comment: Why can't you paste it here? Questions must stand alone. External links rot.

Comment: Because stackoverflow panel this allowed me not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i really do not understand your problem but in simpler terms..this is the code for creating notifications in android:

```
Notification notifica = new Notification();
notifica.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notifica.icon = R.drawable.serie_notification;
notifica.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And to disable sound you have to add this:

```
notifica.defaults = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you Shobhit